# Spawn NodeJS process inside packaged Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

How to spawn a NodeJS process inside a packaged electron app? (with electron-builder)
Somehow I have to provide the node binary, because there are some npm packages which use the binary in their scripts, like: "preinstall": "node ...", therefore I can't use the fork function. Is there any solution to access electron's node and use it for spawn?